# Requiring a mapping class to resolve newly added fields

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mapping, n-tier-architecture

I'm working on a c# project having some tiers with data type encapsulations. But whenever I add a field to a model in a top level layer (say *Application Service*), I need to remember where else should I change to get my application working properly.

I'm looking for a pattern or method to prevent getting potential logical errors followed by not updating my mapping classes. I think if I can require my mapping classes to resolve newly added fields (for example by throwing an exception if they're not resolved), the problem will be solved.

So any idea for a solution? or how I can implement my own idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like automapper that will give you an error if not all properties are mapped properly (http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html), plus it saves you from writing all the code to map each objects.

If you don't want to use a library, make sure to wrap the mappings in factories so that, at least, the code is centralised and easily discoverable, but that's still error prone. Using constructors instead of [object initialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) also helps finding mappings at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. _AutoMapper_ seems good. I read some pages of its documentation, but I'm a little confused how to use it properly. Do you know any online sample which uses _AutoMapper_ in a desktop project?

Comment: Using constructor helps detect mappings too. But when there is a large number of fields within the class, it doesn't seem to be a good choice.